# Wordpress SMTP not working ! Connection Timeout Exceeded

Tags: php, wordpress, email, notifications, smtp

I am working on a WordPress site and while integrating SMTP with the site, I used (EASY WP SMTP & WP Mail SMTP) with 3 different SMTP credentials. When I try to send a test mail over SMTP, it gives me an error (Connection Timeout), and simple SMTP is also not working. I tried to add SMTP and create a test form (contact form) and check, but it didn't send the mail. I am using the BookingPress Plugin, and in that, I also tried SMTP & wp-default, but both are not working. Here is the full error log by Easy WP SMTP:
also i have increased the timeout limit from (10 - 60)

```
Versions:
WordPress: 6.4.3
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 8.1.27
Easy WP SMTP: 2.2.0

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 110 Additional SMTP info: Connection timed out
Host: pop3.mailtrap.io
Port: 1100
SMTPSecure: tls
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(true)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)

Server:
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1w 11 Sep 2023
Apache.mod_security: No

Debug:
Email Source: Easy WP SMTP
Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 110 Additional SMTP info: Connection timed out

SMTP Debug:
2024-03-13 05:58:39 Connection: opening to pop3.mailtrap.io:1100, timeout=30, options=array()

2024-03-13 05:59:09 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to pop3.mailtrap.io:1100 (Connection timed out) [/home/gur1yt4rjmck/public_html/mortgage.cybertrontechnologies.ca/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php line 397]

2024-03-13 05:59:09 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server
```

please help me with this issue

[Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOizs.png)
i want to send the bookingpress notification with smtp and other forms info with smtp but stuck with this error

Comment: First check whether port 1100 traffic is not blocked in your web server

Comment: Please don't take screen shots of your logs instead post as a question